# vue.js test:unit w test-utils & Jest : [vue-test-utils]: wrapper.destroy() can only be called on a Vue instance

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

In order to test a beforeDestroy() hook in my component, I wrote the following spec :

```
 it("should test lifecycle when audio tag is destroyed", () => {
    // jsdom doesn't support any loading or playback media operations. 
    // As a workaround you can add a few stubs in your test setup:
    window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype.removeEventListener = () => { /* do nothing */ };
    // given
    const wrapper = mount(AudioPlayer, {
     // attachToDocument: true,
      propsData: {
        autoPlay: false,
        file: file,
        ended,
        canPlay
      }
    });
    wrapper.vm.loaded = true; // enable buttons
    const player = wrapper.find("#player");
    expect(wrapper.contains('#playPauseBtn')).toBe(true);
    // when
    player.destroy()
    // then
    expect(wrapper.contains('#playPauseBtn')).toBe(false);
  });
```

but I am getting an error, even if the destroy() is used as in the doc ...

[vue-test-utils]: wrapper.destroy() can only be called on a Vue instance

```
  177 |     expect(wrapper.contains('#playPauseBtn')).toBe(true); // OK
  178 |     // when
> 179 |     player.destroy()
```

where am I wrong ?

thanks for feedback

Comment: Your message contains `wrapper` (`wrapper.destroy() can only be...`), but your code (and the marker) leads to `player` (`player.destroy()`) - which one is right?

Comment: I don’t know , this is exactly thé message I get... I don’t understand  either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const player = wrapper.find("#player");` returns a wrapper of DOM element, so basically HTML.

[destroy()](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/destroy.html) destroys a Vue component instance.

You cannot call destroy function on an "HTML element". I believe you wanted to write `wrapper.destroy()`

Comment: thanks a lot ...  wrapper.destroy() is fine ! however I am going to post another question about it